# How do I install Psiphon on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Step by Step)

Tags: command-line

I have tried using Psiphon through Wine but it didn't work.
Please tell me how I can install it using terminal step-by-step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look for this link, it should works for Ubuntu using Wine.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160113152746/https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1926

Install wine:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Install Required Windows DLLs using Wintricks:

- Run Winetricks(from ubuntu dash)
- Choose "Select the default wineprefix" and then press OK.
- Choose "Install a Windows DLL or component" and then press OK.
- Check "wininet" and "winhttp" and then press OK.

Run Psiphon3 and Use the service it provides:

- Simply run Psipon3.exe
- It will provide its service using an "HTTP proxy on localhost port
  8080".
- Use "FoxyProxy" extension on Firefox or "Proxy SwitchySharp"
  extension on chrome for accessing the service.

full details and all rights reserved for the above link

Comment: It's just bring a white screen of psiphon. psiphon version is 102

Comment: @Maythux The link u have provided in the answer says that `the tutorial does not exists` kindly provide some other link please.

Comment: not working, please add more info

Comment: @SnakeEyes See this [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160113152746/https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1926) from the WayBack Machine.

Comment: @Dr.jacky blank page, same with me as we can know from https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2125628#p2125628

Comment: Using a native Linux app is infinitely preferable...

Answer (score 8):

Windows version of Psiphon on wine does not work. Instead of using wine, use native psiphon script for linux.

This linux version by Psiphon Inc. is much better and multifunctional than the windows one.

Here is the simplified,re-shared, modified version of psiphon. Readme contains a simple step by step guide for running psiphon through terminal.

Git Repo :
https://github.com/thispc/psiphon

Clone the repo to get started.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thispc/psiphon.git

$ cd psiphon
```

Open README.md for instructions.

Please ask in case of queries.

Comment: I am not able to run it see https://github.com/thispc/psiphon/issues/3

Comment: How can you say this version if produced by Psiphon Inc.  this is not their Github account ... this readme also ask to re-compile openssh, how can I trust this code ?

Comment: I've completed all the steps mentioned in `README.md` and it runs without giving any errors. Can you explain how can I direct network traffic of a specific program through psiphon?

Comment: @saga you can use redsocks for redirecting all traffic through a particular socks proxy port, to create a system wide proxy. [link](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks)

Comment: I am stucking at https://github.com/thispc/psiphon/issues/23#issuecomment-834723590

Comment: Is there a Python3 fork? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Psiphon Inc. provides Linux binary of `psiphon-tunnel-core` . It does not contain a GUI but very useful. [Download it](https://github.com/Psiphon-Labs/psiphon-tunnel-core-binaries/blob/master/linux/psiphon-tunnel-core-x86_64?raw=true) from [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/Psiphon-Labs/psiphon-tunnel-core-binaries).

After downloading, make it executable with the following:

```bsh
chmod u+x /path/to/downloaded/file
```

Now create a folder and put the following contents to a file named `psiphon.config` inside that folder (copied from my own `psiphon.config`) :

```
{
    "Authorizations":[],
    "DeviceRegion":"US",
    "EgressRegion":"",
    "EmitDiagnosticNetworkParameters":true,
    "EmitDiagnosticNotices":true,
    "EmitServerAlerts":true,
    "LocalHttpProxyPort":8080,
    "LocalSocksProxyPort":1080,
    "NetworkID":"949F2E962ED7A9165B81E977A3B4758B",
    "ObfuscatedServerListRootURLs":
    [
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":0,
            "SkipVerify":false,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3BzaXBob24vd2ViL21qcjQtcDIzci1wdXdsL29zbA=="
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGF0aW5vZmlybWRkaG9zdHMuY29tL3dlYi9tanI0LXAyM3ItcHV3bC9vc2w="
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY29ycG9yYXRlaGlyZXByZXNzdGguY29tL3dlYi9tanI0LXAyM3ItcHV3bC9vc2w="
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ3BhbGx0aGluZ3NudW1iZXJ3ZWF0aGVyLmNvbS93ZWIvbWpyNC1wMjNyLXB1d2wvb3Ns"
        }
    ],
    "PropagationChannelId":"92AACC5BABE0944C",
    "RemoteServerListSignaturePublicKey":"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",
    "RemoteServerListURLs":
    [
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":0,
            "SkipVerify":false,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3BzaXBob24vd2ViL21qcjQtcDIzci1wdXdsL3NlcnZlcl9saXN0X2NvbXByZXNzZWQ="
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGF0aW5vZmlybWRkaG9zdHMuY29tL3dlYi9tanI0LXAyM3ItcHV3bC9zZXJ2ZXJfbGlzdF9jb21wcmVzc2Vk"
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY29ycG9yYXRlaGlyZXByZXNzdGguY29tL3dlYi9tanI0LXAyM3ItcHV3bC9zZXJ2ZXJfbGlzdF9jb21wcmVzc2Vk"
        },
        {
            "OnlyAfterAttempts":2,
            "SkipVerify":true,
            "URL":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ3BhbGx0aGluZ3NudW1iZXJ3ZWF0aGVyLmNvbS93ZWIvbWpyNC1wMjNyLXB1d2wvc2VydmVyX2xpc3RfY29tcHJlc3NlZA=="
        }
    ],
    "ServerEntrySignaturePublicKey":"sHuUVTWaRyh5pZwy4UguSgkwmBe0EHtJJkoF5WrxmvA=",
    "SponsorId":"1BC527D3D09985CF",
    "UseIndistinguishableTLS":true
}
```

Now start `psiphon` with the following:

```bsh
/path/to/downloaded/file -formatNotices -dataRootDirectory /path/to/created/folder -config /path/to/created/folder/psiphon.config
```

Explanation of arguments (from output of `-help` ):

```
  -config string
        configuration input file
  -dataRootDirectory string
        directory where persistent files will be stored
  -formatNotices
        emit notices in human-readable format
```

Here I used `-dataRootDirectory` because without this argument `psiphon` would create a folder named `ca.psiphon.PsiphonTunnel.tunnel-core` at current working directory every time it starts, this argument prevents it.

After executing the command above successfully you should see lots of outputs. When successfully connected you should see something like this:

```
2020-08-08T14:28:05.767Z Homepage {"url":"https://ipfounder.net/?sponsor_id=1BC527D3D09985CF\u0026sponsor=psiphon\u0026client_region=BD\u0026client_asn=24432\u0026client_platform=windows\u0026secret=580EfjEI29xL3hoyU6dgP4vSEVxdcGI7JDFkxgjds7PHulSEF0wmORpvzbqxyTwYtpowsY4xMFnfWEnTghe6l8jiV9K5QSZoir2i6fDeKJD6EhL6DkoYTEMu2EE9YJvy3LdCUZ7ncdVC6ipgWx06wznvDLbY1ajfcfRGCpfsQJei2q6tb0GSFh1QK3x3qXKwyjmNPc5J"}
```

Or you can append `2>&1 | grep 'Homepage {"url"'` to above command which will , here `2>&1` redirects any output from `stderr` to `stdout` and grep searchs for `Homepage {"url"` which indicates connection success.

If you want to use another port for HTTP proxy then change the value of `LocalHttpProxyPort` and to use another port for Socks proxy then change the value of `LocalSocksProxyPort` .

After successful connection configure proxy settings in Settings. If you used default configuration for `psiphon` you can setup proxy settings like this:

[image: Proxy configuration settings]

Comment: How to set the proxy, the terminal endless update... 
https://imgur.com/gallery/g1SgDmd

Answer (score 3):

For the moment the only solution is use the phone as proxy using ssh.

@see https://askubuntu.com/a/881035/48496