# Alternative for psiphon for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any alternative software for psiphon? I have tried TOR, but I am not satisfied with its interface. I need something that is easy to use.

Answer (score 10):

There's no need of an alternative if you have an Android device with you. The idea is to forward the traffic from your Linux machine to the Android device running Psiphon. Follow these steps:

1. Install Psiphon on your Android device. Once installed, always make sure the "**Tunnel Whole Device**" option is checked. Tap connect and verify Internet connectivity (Redundant but necessary).
2. Install SSHdroid on your Android device. By far the best SSH server app I've ever come across. Start the SSH server. If necessary, change the SSH port from 22 (default) to some other number, say 5555.
3. Now, we somehow need to forward the traffic on your Linux machine to the Android device which is running Psiphon. By doing so, we are effectively connecting your Linux machine to the Internet through Psiphon via your Android device. To do so, make sure your **Linux machine and the Android device are in the same LAN** and then, fire up the terminal on your Linux machine and type `ssh -D 8000 -fCqN username@address -p 5555`. The details of this command are beautifully explained in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel) which I highly recommend you to read. In brief, this command creates a local SOCKS proxy server at 127.0.0.1:8000 which maintains a SSH tunnel that connects your Linux machine and the Android device. Use 'username@address' given by SSHdroid. The default password is admin. We now need to forward the traffic to this server using sytem-wide proxy and the rest will be taken care of by this server.
4. If on Ubuntu, go to *System settings > Network > Network Proxy*. Select *Method: Manual*. Put 127.0.0.1 in the *Socks host* field and change the *port* to 8000 (as used in the command). At this step, by forcing system-wide proxy, we are forwarding our traffic to 127.0.0.1:8000 where our local SOCKS proxy server is running which then forwards the traffic to the Android device through the SSH tunnel, which ultimately means your Linux machine is effectively using Psiphon.

If this works for you, you can probably write a script and automate the entire process. Other direct alternatives to Psiphon are highly limited in either bandwidth or data or both, but so is Psiphon as of today. To get around this, use Psiphon client version 103 for literally unlimited access.

Comment: very cleaver it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Lantern is a great alternative for psiphon it's free and open source.
you can download it from [here](https://getlantern.org/).
The source is available at [github](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern).

Answer (score 2):

This 2 are the best alternative to me

- [Lantern](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern-binaries)
- [XX-Net](https://github.com/XX-net/XX-Net)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **I2P**? I don't know all the functionalities of Psiphon but **I2P** is pretty good and simple to use. And it's open-source. Check it [here](https://geti2p.net/en/).

In case you want to use it, you need to either add the repository to your sources, or download the .deb file and install it manually. I recommend the former as it will update automatically (after a `sudo apt-get update` of course) whenever a newer stable release appears.

To install from repositories, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:i2p-maintainers/i2p # this adds the PPA to your sources
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i2p
```

To install from a file, download the .deb from the website, open a terminal, navigate to the .deb file and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That's it.

Now, you might not be aware of [this website](http://alternativeto.net/software/psiphon/?platform=linux). There you have a huge list of software. As you can see **I2P** is recommended by a lot of users. But you might want to check another one. I have only user **ToR** and **I2P**.